# Can "Request Publication" request go to a group other than the admin group in AEM6.1?

Tags: aem

When a user does not have rights to publish a page, he sees `"Request publication"` button in Touch UI editor mode. When he clicks on "`Request Publication`", the workflow "`Request for activation`" starts and go to the admin's inbox. I want the page to go to some other group for publishing. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You might require to create a custom workflow and need to configure wcmworkflowservice to trigger your custom workflow which can handle your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Approve Content Step]

As shown in the image above, you can change the user/group to be anyone/anything in your instance.

You just need to change properties of default "Request for Activation" workflow.

However, it is recommended to make a new workflow of your own so that upgrades and patches don't revert your changes.

Answer (score 0):

On the `/libs/cq/workflow/content/console.html` page with all available workflows. You should find workflow that you are interested in.

In you case it is possibly `http://localhost:4502/cf#/etc/workflow/models/request_for_activation.html`

On this page you can workflow config which contains several steps. Open for editing `Request for activation` step, switch to tab `Arguments` and then you can change `Name patterns` field. It should be regex pattern e.g. `.*approver.*` for all groups which contains `approver` in name.

As a variant you can custom workflow or step. In this case you need to figure out by you self how to configure it but usually it is something similar.